# How to set magic_quotes_gpc to OFF

Tags: ubuntu, php

The magic_quotes_gpc PHP INI directive must be set to 'OFF' in order for
OWA domstreams to operate correctly.

How do you make this change in Plesk server 9.5.4?

Answer (score 3):

There would be several options:

1. IF you are using mod_php - add `.htaccess` file with `php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc off` in docroot of your site
2. IF you are using mod_php and have server admin (root) privileges - create a file `.../conf/vhost.conf` in a folder where your domain is located. You will need assistance of server admin, if you don't have admin privileges.
3. IF you are using CGI/FastCGI and have server admin privileges - edit /etc/php.ini file (impacts all sites). The file may have different location for some OSes, I am not completely sure for its location on Ubuntu.
4. IF you are using CGI/FastCGI and need to apply this setting for one site only - refer to this article http://kb.parallels.com/9059

Alternatively you can upgrade to Plesk 10.4 or Plesk 11.0 and manage PHP settings from UI. It will also ensure your securiyt as older versions of Plesk were a subject of vulnerability recently.